# Как преобразовать приходящее с сервера время iso в нормальный вид android?

Tags: android

У меня в приложении я получаю время, и мне в ответе с сервера приходит время в формате iso. Выглядит оно так:

```
"date": "2018-07-25T16:49:13+02:00"
```

вот у меня собственно возник вопрос - как мне его вывести по-нормальному, то есть выводить например только дату, или дату и время, но по своему формату.

Вероятнее это работа со строками, но я не пойму как раздробить полученную строку и на выходе например приплюсовать те 2 часа какие например указаны в примере?

Comment: Эммм... а причем тут ретрофит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас формат `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. Где Z - TimeZone.

```
DateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    String isoString = "2018-07-25T16:49:13+02:00";
    try {
        Date date = isoFormat.parse(isoString);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(dateString);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String timeString = timeFormat.format(date);
        System.out.println(timeString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Comment: что скоро? не очень понял) скоро дополните ответ, или что?

Comment: скоро дополню) я не успел дописать по обстоятельствам)

Comment: не спешите, и так спасибо что помогаете) удачно справится в вашими обстоятельствами)

Comment: Дополнил, попробуйте

Comment: а как локаль указать в `simpledateformat`, потому-что я так понял что это старый образец написания, может указать еще локаль? или это уже лишнее?

Comment: Пожалуй, тогда подождем более правильное решение) я с локалью не дружу к сожалению, тоже ее не понимаю

Comment: Ваш ответ справляется со своей задачей прекрасно, но мне стало интересно что нужно дописать что-бы студия была спокойна) спасибо за ответ, он вполне рабочий)

Comment: Аааа.... Я не у компа просто. Там вроде в описании ошибки предлагается. Вторым параметром в конструктор `Locale.getDefault()` по моему. Тут подробнее > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023189/simpledateformat-warning-to-get-local-formatting-use-getdateinstance-getdatet